# Blueprism Add Row Number To Collection

Tags: blueprism

I have a collection which I import from Excel. I would like to have a column which tells me the record number. Is this possible?
A) I don't want to have an external counter
B) I don't want to update the excel file to have a line number column.

I can provide screenshots if needed, but can't seem to find anyway to add the functionality I need.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to loop through the collection and add the counter yourself? The performance will be just fine.

Comment: I'm just concerned for the integrity of the job. Would there be a scenario where if the job failed and retried that the counter could fall out of line with the collection? Or should I just have a reset counter at the start of the section?

Comment: Is there no other unique row identifier? Combination of several columns, perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately not, a part of the process is to add each row to a financial system. This will generate the identifier and the bot will update the excel file. Nothing at the start though, other then using the row number and the date concatenated together.

Comment: Ok, I understand. In that case, why not change the source file? Is it a shared file that can be access by other people or is it a file you receive just for the purpose of processing?

Comment: What is the exact use case for needing a row number? We might be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: As it stands it is a shared file, the bot then takes a copy of the relevant data and loads it into a collection. I'd rather not insert a column in the excel itself as I think that would involve creating a simple macro (don't like maintaining external macros). I need the row number in order to generate my own key using that concatenated with the date it's being ran

Comment: So basically you would like to get BluePrism to add the counter between the step it retrieves it from Excel and the step it pushes it into a collection? At least, that's the ideal solution for you? Then that would imply creating a new action in VB or C#. I think I have an object lying about that creates a functionality where one can use SQL queries onto excel worksheets (if you know SQL, you should be able to add the row number pretty easily and concatenate it with the date at the same time)

Comment: Hi Jerry, yes that would be bang on. I know SQL so that sounds ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, my proposed solution will use a bit of SQL inside some C# code blocks. The difference with my comment is that I thought I could use the MSSQL Syntax in the SQL query, which wasn't the case (for instance, `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't work...), so I had to do a bit of googling and testing on my side. But yea it works and enough of the blabbering, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new object (proposed name "MS Excel - SQL") and in the Initialise page, add `System.Data.OleDb` to the Namespace Imports and set the language to C#:

   [image]
2. In the same initialise stage, insert the following code in the Global Code tab:

   ```
   public DataTable GetDataFromExcel (string filename,string sql)
   {
       DataTable dt; 
       OleDbConnection MyConnection;
       DataSet DtSet;
       OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

       MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filename+" Properties=Excel 12.0;");
       MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, MyConnection);
       DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

       MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
       dt = DtSet.Tables[0];
       MyConnection.Close();
       return dt;
   }
   ```

   [image]
3. Click OK, rename Action 1 appropriately, e.g. "Excel Query with Row Number" and insert a new Code stage (it's advised to name it properly as well):

   [image]
4. You will at least need the path to the file, the sheet name and the query for inputs, and a collection for output:

   [image]
5. Put the variables in the Start and End stages and in the Code tab, insert the following:

   ```
   Results = GetDataFromExcel(@"" + File_Path + ";Extended", Query + " FROM [" + Worksheet_Name + "$]");

   Results.Columns.Add("RowNumber", typeof(int));

   int Row = 1;
   foreach (DataRow ThisRow in Results.Rows)
   {
       ThisRow["RowNumber"] = Row;
       Row++;
   }
   ```

   [image]
6. Save the object and you can now call this action from Process View. File path and Worksheet Name and Results should be straight forward, for the query, you can use something like `SELECT *` or select specific columns (recommended) such as with `SELECT [Column 1], [Column 2]`. Your Results collection will contain those columns, with an additional column called `RowNumber`. You can generate the identifier from this collection (add column, then loop to concatenate the date), or tweak the code stage in the object to add another column and fill it with Row and Date concatenated (except it will be less flexible as an object after that).

Comment: Also my C# skills aren't top notch, so I am open to suggestions for improvements on that part.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am getting an error Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.. I'm guessing I don't have something installed that needs to be?

Comment: @E_McAndrew I think that's MS Access. Can you try to see if [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb) is of any use? Unfortunately I can't really help you properly with that since it works fine on my machine :(

Comment: Turns out Access wasn't installed! Thanks

Comment: I just realised this object was basically a shorter version for using the Data = OLEDB object provided by BP. I stumbled on an issue where the ACE.OLEDB version has changed and am trying to figure out how to make the bot itself figure out which version to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking if you can do this:
1. Import the content of excel to your first collection.
2. Create a new collection then create a stage that copies the data from first collection via loop

[image]

Comment: How would this add in a row number column?

Comment: first loop into first collection then add an action add row then calculation stage to set values into it

Comment: Is that not going to be the same as me simply having a counter, inserting the value into each line of my original collection?

Comment: i edited my answer for you to imagine what the flow will look like

Comment: I appreciate the screenshot etc, but this just looks more long winded then adding another column to my collection and inserting the values there? I did ask not to use an external counter i.e. (your row number data item). I'm looking for either a functionality that can pull a collections row number, or like Jerry's comment.